# How to configure JRE to run on specific font

Tags: java, fonts

I've downloaded the java open source gui POS software and would like to change it to be able to display non-unicode font which include our local language.

I know that I can change the font of the gui components by `component.setFont(new java.awt.Font("MyFont", 1, 14))` but there are a lot of components to change in order to make it display. Instead, I think changing the JRE default font will be a lot easy than changing the code.

According to [Java Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html), I've tried like the following so far - but it's not working.

Changed `fontconfig.properties.src` to `fontconfig.properties` under `jre/lib/`

**In fontconfig.properties**

Changed the font names to the one I want like this.

```
serif.plain.alphabetic=Times New Roman (=> serif.plain.alphabetic=MyFont)
sansserif.plain.alphabetic=Arial (=> serif.plain.alphabetic=MyFont)
monospaced.plain.alphabetic=Courier New (=> serif.plain.alphabetic=MyFont)
dialog.plain.alphabetic=Arial (=> serif.plain.alphabetic=MyFont)
dialoginput.plain.alphabetic=Courier New (=> serif.plain.alphabetic=MyFont)
```

and finally added this line.

```
filename.MyFont=MyFont.ttf
```

**System Info:**

```
Windows 7, jdk1.7.0
```

What am I doing wrong? Any advice would be very appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: I've the same issue. I modified fontconfig.properties on Windows but it doesn't seem to work. I had specified sansserif and monospace fonts. The monospace fonts have changed but not the sansserif one. Did the suggested solution work for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also looking for a way to change the jre's default font, editing `fontconfig.properties` worked for me actually (oracle java 6, linux in my case):

- edit `jre/lib/fontconfig.Ubuntu.properties`
- To change the default font replace all `DejaVu Sans` with `Ubuntu` for example, and add the path to the font files:

  ```
  # Font File Names

  filename.Ubuntu=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-R.ttf
  filename.Ubuntu_Bold=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf
  filename.Ubuntu_Oblique=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-RI.ttf
  filename.Ubuntu_Bold_Oblique=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-BI.ttf

  filename.Ubuntu_Mono=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/UbuntuMono-R.ttf
  filename.Ubuntu_Mono_Bold=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/UbuntuMono-B.ttf
  filename.Ubuntu_Mono_Oblique=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/UbuntuMono-RI.ttf
  filename.Ubuntu_Mono_Bold_Oblique=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/UbuntuMono-BI.ttf
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a custom look and feel. This will allow you to change the font and many other things. You can base it off [Nimbus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html), or [Syth](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html). [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/LookAndFeel.html) is the main look and feel java doc. Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/lookandfeel/index.html) for some examples on modifying the look and feel.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I search their forum and found out that pos is customized with look and feel. Does look and feel override the changes in code? I changed setFont method in java code but it did't take effect. Where am I start looking to change look and feel of that program?

Comment: I believe the look and feel sets the default, well, look and feel. For whatever reason, your code is having trouble changing the default.